# Handeling and reporting errors that thrown inside runZonedGuarded callback [Crashlytics, Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, crashlytics

I am implementing Crashlytics with flutter,
and following this docs [Using Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/)

I was wondering what would actually happen if an error is thrown inside runZonedGuarded's
error callback: (see the arrow in the code)

```
void main() async {
  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;

    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stackTrace) async {
      ***** some buggy code here ******.   <----------
     await crashlytics.handleNonFlutterErrors(error,stackTrace);
  });;
}
```

so I have tried it, and to my surprise it is still swallowed by flutter framework and stacktrace was dumped to console - I was expecting the app to crash but it didn't...

does any-body knows how to handle this types of errors?

Comment: Like any other exception, just wrap it inside try/catch. Flutter apps normally don't crash even if you do not handle an exception. It takes some time getting used to as is the opposite of android.

Comment: @croxx5f thanks for your answer, but where exactly flutter handles the errors thrown from there, does it have an higher level of zone where I can integrate?